# Change Group permission using JSOM in SP 2013

Tags: permissions, groups, jsom, roles

I'm trying to change the permissions of an SP Group in an SPWeb using JSOM. I can add a new role using a new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection oblect to the group. But a similar approach to remove a role definition fails with an error saying:

> Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference

Here is the code I use:

```
var clientContext;
var currentWeb;
var groupCollection;
var pMGroup;

function CloseProjectSite(siteTitle)
{
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://site collection/myweb');
    currentWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    pMGroup = groupCollection.getByName(siteTitle + ' Project Managers');

    //Get Role Definition by name
    var rdRead = currentWeb.get_roleDefinitions().getByName('Read');
    var rdContribute = currentWeb.get_roleDefinitions().getByName('Contribute');
    // Create a new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.
    var collRead = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    var collContribute = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    // Add the role to the collection.
    collRead.add(rdRead);
    collContribute.add(rdContribute);

    // Get the RoleAssignmentCollection for the target web.
    var assignments = currentWeb.get_roleAssignments();

    // assign the group to the new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.
    var roleAssignmentRead = assignments.add(pMGroup, collRead);        

    var roleAssignmentContribute = assignments.remove(pMGroup, collContribute);        

    clientContext.load(currentWeb);
    clientContext.load(pMGroup);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.CloseProjectSiteSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.CloseProjectSiteFailed));
});
}
```

It seems the RoleDefinitionBindingCollection doesn't have a

> remove

function. Has anybody come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. You should first get the Role Assignment if the group from the role assignment collection of the web.Then use [importRoleDefinitionBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659243(v=office.14).aspx)  method of the roleassignment object to add the **Read**  role definition binding. This will remove the existing bindings and add the new binding.

```
var clientContext;
    var currentWeb;
    var groupCollection;
    var pMGroup;

function CloseProjectSite(siteTitle)
{
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://site collection/myweb');
    currentWeb = clientContext.get_web();

    //Get Role Definition by name
    var rdRead = currentWeb.get_roleDefinitions().getByName('Read');
    // Create a new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.
    var collRead = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(clientContext);
    // Add the role to the collection.
    collRead.add(rdRead);
    // Get the RoleAssignmentCollection for the target web.
    var assignments = currentWeb.get_roleAssignments();
     //Get the role assignment for the group using Group  's membership id
    var groupRoleAssignment=assignments.getByPrincipalId(23);
    groupRoleAssignment.importRoleDefinitionBindings(collRead);
    groupRoleAssignment.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.CloseProjectSiteSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.CloseProjectSiteFailed));
});
}
```